# Getting SQL error while joining the multiple table using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting the following error while trying to join multiple table using different condition in PHP and MySQL.

> Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY

Here is my query:

```
select
   b.member_id,
   b.rest_name,
   b.city,
   b.proviance,
   b.postal,
   b.address,
   b.country,
   b.person,
   b.mobile,
   b.url,
   b.status,
   b.premium,
   b.image,
   b.business_phone_no,
   b.email,
   b.multiple_image,
   b.latitude,
   b.longitude,
   b.quadrant,
   d.member_id,
   d.day_id,
   d.cat_id,
   d.subcat_id,
   d.comment,
   d.city,
   d.special_images,
   c.cat_id,
   c.special,
   sub.subcat_id,
   sub.subcat_name,
   sub.status,
   sl.day_id,
   sl.member_id,
   sl.date_from,
   sl.date_to 
from
   db_restaurant_basic as b 
   left join
      db_restaurant_detail as d 
      on b.member_id = d.member_id 
   left join
      db_category as c 
      on d.cat_id = c.cat_id 
   left join
      db_subcategory as sub 
      on d.subcat_id = sub.subcat_id 
   left join
      db_special_images as sl 
      on d.day_id = sl.day_id 
      and d.member_id = sl.member_id 
where
   b.city = '2' 
   and d.day_id = '3' 
   and c.special = '2' 
   and sl.date_from <= '2016-10-26' 
   and sl.date_to >= '2016-10-26' 
   and b.status = 1 
   and sub.status = 1 
   and sl.date_from != '' 
   and sl.date_to != '' 
ORDER BY
   b.member_id DESC 
UNION ALL
SELECT
   b.member_id,
   b.rest_name,
   b.city,
   b.proviance,
   b.postal,
   b.address,
   b.country,
   b.person,
   b.mobile,
   b.url,
   b.status,
   b.premium,
   b.image,
   b.business_phone_no,
   b.email,
   b.multiple_image,
   b.latitude,
   b.longitude,
   b.quadrant,
   d.member_id,
   d.day_id,
   d.cat_id,
   d.subcat_id,
   d.comment,
   d.city,
   d.special_images,
   c.cat_id,
   c.special,
   sub.subcat_id,
   sub.subcat_name,
   sub.status,
   sl.day_id,
   sl.member_id,
   sl.date_from,
   sl.date_to 
from
   db_restaurant_basic as b 
   left join
      db_restaurant_detail as d 
      on b.member_id = d.member_id 
   left join
      db_category as c 
      on d.cat_id = c.cat_id 
   left join
      db_subcategory as sub 
      on d.subcat_id = sub.subcat_id 
   left join
      db_special_images as sl 
      on d.day_id = sl.day_id 
      and d.member_id = sl.member_id 
where
   b.city = '2' 
   and d.day_id = '3' 
   and c.special = '2' 
   and b.status = 1 
   and sub.status = 1 
   and sl.date_from = '' 
   and sl.date_to = '' 
ORDER BY
   b.member_id DESC
```

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assign order by only an the end of the query not inside each select
and using proper alias for columns with same name in different table

```
select 
     b.member_id as b_member_id
    ,b.rest_name
    ,b.city
    ,b.proviance
    ,b.postal
    ,b.address
    ,b.country
    ,b.person
    ,b.mobile
    ,b.url
    ,b.status
    ,b.premium
    ,b.image
    ,b.business_phone_no
    ,b.email
    ,b.multiple_image
    ,b.latitude
    ,b.longitude
    ,b.quadrant
    ,d.member_id as d_member_id
    ,d.day_id
    ,d.cat_id
    ,d.subcat_id
    ,d.comment
    ,d.city
    ,d.special_images
    ,c.cat_id
    ,c.special
    ,sub.subcat_id
    ,sub.subcat_name
    ,sub.status
    ,sl.day_id
    ,sl.member_id
    ,sl.date_from
    ,sl.date_to 
from db_restaurant_basic as b 
left join db_restaurant_detail as d on b.b_member_id=d.d_member_id 
left join db_category as c on d.cat_id=c.cat_id 
left join db_subcategory as sub on d.subcat_id=sub.subcat_id 
left join db_special_images as sl on d.day_id=sl.day_id and d.member_id=sl.member_id 
where b.city='2' 
  and d.day_id='3' 
  and c.special='2' 
  and sl.date_from <='2016-10-26' 
  and sl.date_to >= '2016-10-26' 
  and b.status=1 
  and sub.status=1 
  and sl.date_from !='' 
  and sl.date_to !='' 

UNION ALL 

SELECT 
     b.member_id
    ,b.rest_name
    ,b.city
    ,b.proviance
    ,b.postal
    ,b.address
    ,b.country
    ,b.person
    ,b.mobile
    ,b.url
    ,b.status
    ,b.premium
    ,b.image
    ,b.business_phone_no
    ,b.email
    ,b.multiple_image
    ,b.latitude
    ,b.longitude
    ,b.quadrant
    ,d.member_id
    ,d.day_id
    ,d.cat_id
    ,d.subcat_id
    ,d.comment
    ,d.city
    ,d.special_images
    ,c.cat_id
    ,c.special
    ,sub.subcat_id
    ,sub.subcat_name
    ,sub.status
    ,sl.day_id
    ,sl.member_id
    ,sl.date_from
    ,sl.date_to 
from db_restaurant_basic as b 
left join db_restaurant_detail as d on b.member_id=d.member_id 
left join db_category as c on d.cat_id=c.cat_id 
left join db_subcategory as sub on d.subcat_id=sub.subcat_id 
left join db_special_images as sl on d.day_id=sl.day_id and d.member_id=sl.member_id 
where b.city='2' 
  and d.day_id='3' 
  and c.special='2' 
  and b.status=1 
  and sub.status=1 a
  nd sl.date_from ='' 
  and sl.date_to ='' 
ORDER BY b_member_id DESC
```

Comment: I did as per you but its throwing this `Unknown column 'b.member_id' in 'order clause'` error again.

Comment: I have update the asnwer  adding an alias cor b.member_id and using this alias i  order  by .. let me know

Comment: its again throwing this ` #1052 - Column 'member_id' in order clause is ambiguous` error.

Comment: I have update the asnwer adding b_member_id and using the alias only

Comment: again this ` #1054 - Unknown column 'b_member_id' in 'on clause'` error is coming.

Comment: Just for debug ..i have update the asnwer with the first query and  try remove the order by clause from the bottom .. of the query .. (try without order  by , without alias and with original table col)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126396/discussion-between-satya-and-scaisedge).